Две одинаковые части в вопросе
Есть такое предложение: «Скоро ведь осень, да?» Мне почему-то кажется, что здесь ведь и да – это одно и то же, то есть они оба находятся во фразе для того, чтобы показать неуверенность человека в чём-либо и желание узнать это у собеседника. Действительно ли это так? Лучше ли будет поменять фразу на «Скоро осень, да?» или «Скоро ведь осень?»?
Такого же рода вопрос и насчёт другого предложения: «И тем не менее... она всё равно защитила Сару». Здесь тоже конструкции тем не менее и всё равно будто делают одно и то же: показывают, что действие совершено вопреки чему-то.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть с двумя такими предложениями.


И тем не менее... она всё равно защитила Сару.

Уступительная конструкция: Хотя были причины не делать этого, она тем не менее всё равно защитила Сару.
Тавтология? Нет, это усиление противительного значения.
Справочник: ВСЁ РАВНО, 3. Частица (в предложении с противительным, условным, уступительным союзом). Служит для усиления противопоставления сказанному ранее; то же, что «всё-таки, тем не менее». Не требует постановки знаков препинания.  На плечи я накинул какую-то мешковину, но всё равно быстро весь промок... В. Аксенов, Пора, мой друг, пора.

Скоро ведь осень, да?

Словарь ВЕДЬ. I. частица. Употр. для усиления основного содержания всего высказывания (предположения, утверждения, вопроса и т.п.) или выделения, подчёркивания отдельного слова. В. приди я вовремя, этого бы не случилось. В. поступи я иначе, всё обошлось бы. Вы в. всё равно не пойдёте.
Частица ведь усиливает утвердительный смысл высказывания, но потом появляются сомнения. Здесь есть значение уступки: Хотя я так думаю, но ведь могу и ошибаться. Но тавтологии нет.
